# Updated chrome to 109.0.5414.74, scrolling don't stop on finders up (need to keep fingers immobilized for a few seconds)

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, scrolling

Under Ubuntu 22.04, just ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, I saw chrome got updated. Installed version is now `Version 109.0.5414.74 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

And now, when I want to stop the scrolling mid-page, if I remove my fingers too fast from the touchpad, the scrolling restarts! Before the upgrade I'm sure I didn't have to immobilize my fingers that much time to really stop the scrolling.

It makes chrome unusable :(

FYI, below are the flags I've changed.

Thanks for your help!

[image]